# Usage of "hasta" in time phrases

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

How does `hasta` translate in the following sentence?

> **Acá viví hasta los veinte años.**

Which of the following would be the appropriate way to read it?

> *1. I lived here for 20 years.*
>
> *2. I lived here until I was 20.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one. `Hasta` is used to denote a period of time, but it conveys the meaning of `until`, not `for`.

`Hasta` can have different meanings:

- until / till

> Me voy a quedar en España hasta el final de las navidades  <sub>I'm going to stay in Spain until the end of Christmas</sub>
>
> Nos quedamos hasta el final <sub>We stayed till the very end</sub>

- up to

> Llené el vaso hasta arriba  <sub>I filled the glass up to the top</sub>

- down to

> La temperatura cayó hasta los -10 grados  <sub>Temperature drop down to -10 degrees</sub>
>
> A veces se pasa hasta una hora viendo la tele  <sub>Sometimes he spends up to one hour watching tv</sub>

- as far as

> Los pájaros volaron hasta el horizonte  <sub>The birds flew as far as the horizon</sub>

- even

> Hasta mi propio hermano cree que grito mucho  <sub>Even my own brother thinks I yell too much</sub>
>
> Hasta los niños saben eso  <sub>Even toddlers know that</sub>

- including

> Limpió (toda la casa) hasta el garaje  <sub>He cleaned everything, including the garage</sub>